# How can I add double bonds to Triazine-derivatives for OpenBabel generation of pdbqt files?

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, openbabel

The double bonds are initially present at the sdf file but disappear or are misplaced after `.pdbqt` conversion. I tried all kinds of combinations using renumbering atoms, manually including connect bonds or connect bonds, changing A atoms to Cs, NA atoms to N, small case lettering, `.sdf`, `.pdb` or `.mol` inputs. Nothing worked!!!.

When any of those alternative solutions were converted by OpenBabel to their corresponding `.pdbqt`, none of them interpret the double bonds of triazine (`c1ncncn1`) correctly. Furthermore, sometimes  they introduced double bonds in other parts of the molecules, misplaced them or broke them.

I enclose two of my Triazine derivatives in the `.sdf` format.

```
136627870N3+2.2
  MOLSOFT 09022111472D

 29 30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000 O   0  0  0
    1.2534    0.7910   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -1.3507    0.7910   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    2.5067    0.0608   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -2.7014    0.0608   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    2.4581   -1.3994   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    3.7601    0.8518   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    3.7114   -2.1295   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
    1.1073   -2.1295   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
    3.7114    2.4094   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    3.6628   -3.5898   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    1.0587   -3.5898   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    2.4337    3.1639   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    2.3120   -4.3199   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
    4.9161   -4.3199    0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -0.2920   -4.3199   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
    2.3851    4.7214   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    4.8675   -5.7801    0.0000 C   0  0  3
    6.1695   -3.5289   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -1.6428   -3.5289   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -0.3407   -5.7801   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    3.5167   -6.5102    0.0000 O   0  0  0
    6.1208   -6.5102    0.0000 C   0  0  0
    7.4229   -4.2590   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -1.6914   -1.9713   -0.0000 O   0  0  0
   -1.6914   -6.5102   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    7.3742   -5.7314   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -3.0422   -5.7314   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -4.3929   -6.4616   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
  1  2  1
  1  3  1
  2  4  1
  3  5  1
  4  6  1
  4  7  1
  6  8  2
  6  9  1
  7 10  1
  8 11  1
  9 12  2
 10 13  1
 11 14  2
 11 15  1
 12 16  1
 12 14  1
 13 17  1
 15 19  1
 16 20  1
 16 21  1
 18 15  1
 18 22  1
 18 23  1
 19 24  1
 20 25  1
 21 26  1
 23 27  1
 24 27  1
 26 28  1
 28 29  1
M  END
> <molFormula>
C20H38N6O3

> <smiles>
CCCCN(CO)c1nc(nc(n1)N1CCCCC1O)N(CCCC)COCC

$$$$
135839733N3+1.3
  MOLSOFT 09022111472D

 25 27  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000 O   0  0  0
    0.0250    1.4637    0.0000 C   0  0  3
   -1.2260    2.2018    0.0000 N   0  0  0
    1.2260    2.1768    0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -2.4771    1.4387   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -1.2761    3.7281   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
    1.2135    3.7782   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -3.8032    2.2269   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -2.4521   -0.0626   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -0.0500    4.5163   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -5.0542    1.4637   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -3.7031   -0.8257   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -5.0292   -0.0375   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -6.3803    2.2519   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -3.6781   -2.3269   -0.0000 N   0  0  0
   -6.4304    3.7782   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -7.7065    1.5388   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -2.3770   -3.0901   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -5.0042   -3.0400   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -7.7565    4.5663   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -9.0326    2.3269   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -1.0759   -2.3520   -0.0000 O   0  0  0
   -5.0542   -4.4787   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -9.0826    3.8532   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
   -3.7531   -5.2419   -0.0000 C   0  0  0
  2  1  1
  2  3  1
  2  4  1
  3  5  1
  3  6  1
  4  7  1
  5  8  2
  5  9  1
  6 10  1
  7 10  1
  8 11  1
  9 12  2
 11 13  2
 11 14  1
 12 15  1
 12 13  1
 14 16  1
 14 17  1
 15 18  1
 15 19  1
 16 20  1
 17 21  1
 18 22  1
 19 23  1
 20 24  1
 21 24  1
 23 25  1
M  END
> <molFormula>
C17H30N6O2

> <smiles>
CCCN(CO)c1nc(nc(n1)N1CCCCC1O)N1CCCCC1

$$$
```

Comment: I moved the comments here, along with the prior chatroom discussion, to a chatroom for this site: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59075397#59075397. The moved chat comments are a bit further up in the room (they are sorted chronologically while the comments from this post are all listed as when they were moved.

Comment: There is a dedicated Open Babel mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/projects/openbabel/lists/openbabel-discuss

Comment: Thank you Geoff. I wil contact them. For AutoDockVina I use the PyRx package gui for Vina. It is easier to handle,it parallelises the work and also contains OpenBable.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems the user has decided to redirect their question to OpenBabel support and has not returned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP returns.